# Console Application: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point - While Main exists

Tags: .net-core, console-application, .net-5

My .NET 5 project's `Program.cs` looks like this:

using System;

```
namespace XmlGenerator.Cli
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("Boo!!!"));
        }
    }
}
```

And my project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Master.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Program.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Master.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I try and run the app with `F5`, I get the following error:

```
CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

I certainly does contain a `Main`, so what could be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<Compile Remove="Program.cs" />` line?

Comment: It's pretty clear your project file is messed up: Your code file `Program.cs` has build action `Content` and is marked as `Copy to Output directory - Copy always`. If you didn't change this yourself and can reproduce this for every new project of that type, the project template is broken.

Comment: If you want to fix this project and don't want to mess with your project file directly, go to `Properties` of your `Program.cs` and set `Build Action` to `C# Compiler` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`.

Comment: If you found the solution, put it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to delete all the `ItemGroup` elements from the project file, leaving just:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```